# Kotlin @Serializable annotation not working in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm trying to use the `@Serializable` annotation in Kotlin. I can build the project with Gradle, but it's showing up red in IntelliJ and when I hover on the `@Serializable` annotation, there's a message saying:

```
 kotlinx.serializable compiler plugin is not applied to the module, so this
 annotation would not be processed. Make sure you've setup your buildscript
 correctly and re-import project.
```

My `build.gradle.kts` file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm").version("1.3.50")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.3.50"
    idea
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation(group = "com.charleskorn.kaml", name = "kaml", version = "0.12.0")

    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}
```

I have the most recent version of the Kotlin plugin (1.3.50) installed.

Comment: Just checked your config - everything works fine. Try to refresh Gradle (in IDE), or/and restart IDE.

Comment: Hmm, which version of IntelliJ do you have? Specifically this code is red:

`DataClassWithSerializableAnnotation.serializer()`

Comment: Also, how do you "import" the project into IntelliJ? I run `./gradlew idea` and then open the generated project.

Comment: IntelliJ idea ultimate 2019.2 EAP. I have just created new project and replaced build.gradle with *.kts

Comment: Heya @MaxFarsikov, I got this working. The trick was to import the project by opening the `build.gradle.kts` file rather than run `./gradlew idea`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: None of these work for the default Intellij build system, which I think is Ant, yet I have the problem... Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is about Gradle + IntelliJ. IntelliJ doesn't really have a default build system, and if it did it would not be Ant. :) I would ask a new question about your specific problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to add :

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.21"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.4.21"
}
```

This is specified by JetBrains here, linked to gradle:

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#setup

https://ktor.io/docs/kotlin-serialization.html#add_dependencies

Answer (score 17):

In my case I needed to add jvm plugin at *project-level* gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.7.20' apply false   
}
```

then in *app gradle* I added

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.7.20'
}
```

with this configuration I am able to see:

```
Record.serializer()
```

Answer (score 5):

So I got this working. The problem was that I was using the `idea` plugin to generate the IntelliJ project. When I instead imported the project by opening the `build.gradle.kts` file, everything works as expected.

The reason I didn't import it that way in the first place is because I had disabled Gradle support, so when I opened the `build.gradle.kts` file, it didn't import the project, it just opened it in an editor. If you have this situation, hit `cmd`+`shift`+`a` and search for `Gradle` and then toggle that switch to `On`. After a reboot of IntelliJ you should be able to import the project from the `build.gradle.kts` file and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the `main` and `test` directories were no longer 'modules' in IntelliJ. Not sure what happened...

You can verify this by going to the `menu -> File -> Project Structure...`

Under the `modules` left side navigation the `main` and `test` should be modules under the parent app. If not, the easiest way to fix is

- Close your project
- Delete the .idea and .gradle directories
- Select `Menu -> File -> New project from existing source...` and import as a gradle project

Otherwise, you could also likely recreate your modules by going to `Project structure...` shown above. Then `+ New Module` under your parent app, then select Java, with Kotlin checked as the module type. Do this for both the `main` and `test` dirs (ensure your directories are marked as 'test' source directories in the latter)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Maven to build then you need

```
    <configuration>
        <compilerPlugins>
            <plugin>kotlinx-serialization</plugin>
        </compilerPlugins>
    </configuration>
```

As described here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#maven

I had deleted that bit from my pom.xml because it compiled fine from the command line but then I hit this error under IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I tried using a version of the plugin that didn't match my Kotlin version:

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false
    // other plugins
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.23" apply false
}
```

Once I changed it to match and re-synced Gradle the issue went away.

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false
    // other plugins
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.10" apply false
}
```