# Kotlin throwing error "Polymorphic serializer was not found for missing class discriminator ('null')"

Tags: android, json, kotlin, ktor

I have this JSON response:

```
{
  "Appetizers": {
    "menu": [
      "Spinach Artichoke Dip",
      "Hummus",
      "Fried Calamari Rings",
      "Fried Mushrooms"
    ]
  },
  "Salads": {
    "menu": [
      "Greek",
      "Caesar",
      "Mediterranean Tuna Salad",
      "Grilled Chicken Salad"
    ]
  },
  "Drinks": {
    "menu": [
      "Water",
      "Coke",
      "Beer",
      "Iced Tea"
    ]
  },
  "Dessert": {
    "menu": [
      "Baklawa",
      "Ice cream"
    ]
  }
}
```

this is my Kotlin Client:

```kotlin
    private val client = HttpClient(Android) {
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                json(
                    contentType = ContentType("text", "plain"))
            }
        }
```

This code throws the crash error:

```kotlin
    @Serializable
    class MenuCategory(
        val menu: List<String>
    )

 

    val response: Map<String, MenuCategory> =
                client.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Meta-Mobile-Developer-PC/Working-With-Data-API/main/littleLemonMenu.json")
 
                  .body()
```

The error message:

> io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input
> Caused by: kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Polymorphic
> serializer was not found for missing class discriminator ('null')
> JSON input: .....er","Iced Tea"]},"Dessert":{"menu":["Baklawa","Ice
> cream"]}}

How do i fix this?

Comment: I missed a warning earlier This solved for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57701850/kotlin-serializable-annotation-not-working-in-intellij